# RabbitMQ. Masstransit. Virtual Hosts.

Tags: rabbitmq, virtualhost, masstransit

how can I create virtual host from masstransit service bus configuration?

I mean, for example, I deployed my app to some new PC and it should create new virtual host for itself.

I'm trying do this like this:

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseRabbitMq();
                sbc.UseHealthMonitoring(10);
                sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/mynewcustomvhost/myqueue?temporary=true");
            });
```

But getting error:

```
"No Obvious Problems says ConfigurationResult"
```

Why so?

Comment: Does "mynewcustomvhost" exist? If not, create it. Make sure guest/guest can access it or add a user/pw as show below. Does myqueue already exist? If it does, delete it as a temporary queue can not exist in advance. Other errors, check the RabbitMQ log for broker errors if they are logged by MT using either Log4Net and NLog.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
  sbc.UseRabbitMq(r =>
                  {
                      r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://hostname/vhost/queue"), h =>
                      {
                          h.SetUsername("username");
                          h.SetPassword("password");
                      });
                  });

  // other options
});
```

Comment: It's just a regular connection. It will not create vhost. It will just use existing one. I alriedy discover that you you should use Rest API from RabbitMQ management plugin in order to create new vhosts.