# MassTransit Request Response sample

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm learning about MassTransit, so I downloaded the [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse) they have however it doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm getting the following error when I try to start the service:

```
An exception occurred
MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect failed: igor@localhost:5672/test ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=530, text="NOT_ALLOWED - vhost test not found", classId=10, methodId=40, cause=
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

When I try to use other examples using older versions of MassTransit they are working fine.

Comment: Here is my code that uses vanilla RMQ without vhosts https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/MTSamples.RequestResponsePerf/blob/master/RequestResponse/Program.cs

Comment: Thank you for your response Alexey. As I said I'm learning this now, so I'm not entirely sure what a virtual host even means in this case. Also as this is the example that's supplied by Mass transit I would expect the code to work (if need be create the vhost for me?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample uses a RMQ URI, which includes the `test` virtual host. Since you have not created it, your code fails and it actually tells you exactly this - virtual host `test` is not found.

Here is the [app.config](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse/blob/master/src/RequestService/App.config#L8) from that sample:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RabbitMQHost" value="rabbitmq://localhost/test"/>
    <add key="ServiceQueueName" value="request_service"/>
</appSettings>
```

Hence that the client [uses the same URI,](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse/blob/master/src/Client/App.config#L8) so both of them will fail starting.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alexey, this does explain what the problem is, but as I'm just learning about MassTransit I have no idea how to create vhosts. I did a search but I cant find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092932/rabbitmq-masstransit-virtual-hosts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Ok I got how I can do it using RabbitMq management, however is this not possible from code?

Comment: vhosts are infrastructure. You should use RMQ CLI or management UI to create them, not MT code.

Comment: I submitted a PR to add these expectations to the Requirements in the README file.